# Slow meteor.js on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on a meteor project and I'm the only dev using a linux machine. The project runs fine on all other devs (OSX) but on mine it's extremely slow. I'm talking minutes.

I've tried upgrading meteor and node and even reinstalling the whole OS. 
It slows down on any major command, but mostly on `meteor` or `meteor test`. Usually, the most slow part is the `Building Application/Selecting package` step.

Any hints?

Here's my configuration

- Gnome Ubuntu 16.04.1
- Node v6.3.1
- Npm 3.10.3
- Meteor 1.4.0.1

My Machine is an i7, 16GB RAM with an 256GB SSD

Comment: Unfortunately it's a well known [issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4284)

Comment: @JeanMel I was followinf this issue/thread, but the promisse was that 1.4 would solve this issue (or at leats make it easier to handle) but so far, nothing :(

Comment: Did you try to put all your components in the `client/imports` directory (if you use angular2) ?